# Create a new column with labels bases on a different columns values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I am trying to create a new column based on values of a different column to essentially label the values in a different column into two buckets.

so if the dates of 4/24, 4/26 I wanted labels of 1 and 4/25 label of 2,

expected df would look like:

```
date | label 
4/24     1
4/25     2
4/26     1
4/24     1
4/26     1
```

where label would be the new column

Thanks for looking

Comment: You need to add more detail to your question (i.e. what would you expect the outocome dataframe to look like)? No idea with  how it's phrased now.

Comment: Thanks, @EHB that df sample I included would be the expected outcome

Comment: To put it another way, on this site we ask that users provide a [mcve] for the problem you're trying to solve, including sample input and output, and what you've tried so far. For instance, you haven't showed your previous efforts, or described how you got these labels from this input data

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
dataframe["date"] = ['4/24', '4/25', '4/26', '4/24', '4/26']

dictionary = {'4/24' : '1', '4/25' : '2', '4/26':'1' }
dataframe["label"] = dataframe["date"].map(dictionary)
dataframe
```

Create a dictionary so that we can map each and every labels with their dates. You can change the dictionary accordingly.

Output:

```
date    label
0   4/24    1
1   4/25    2
2   4/26    1
3   4/24    1
4   4/26    1
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a classification function

```
def classify(date):
    # returns a label for date
```

Then you can achieve what you need:

```
df['label'] = pd.Series(classify(df['date'].values), index=df.index)
```

Comment: I guess thats my question for example if I want  4/24, 4/26 to have labels of 1 and 4/25 label of 2 how would I enter that as code into that function?

Answer (score 0):

Um, so if you want to print the said column, you could just do this:

```py
print(date | label)
dates = ['4/24', '4/25', '4/26', '4/24', '4/26']
labels = ['1','2','1','2','1']
for i in range(len(dates)):
    print(dates[i]+'     '+labels[i])
```

I gues this would be what you wanted

That is considering you have all your labels and dates in two lists, ordered by index.

Or you could do this:

```py
datesToBePrinted = zip(dates, labels)
for i in datesToBePrinted:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this very specific case, you only need to check if the last character is `5` so you can have a very nice vectorize function:

```
df['label'] = df['date'].str[-1].eq('5') + 1
```

Output:

```
   date  label
0  4/24      1
1  4/25      2
2  4/26      1
3  4/24      1
4  4/26      1
```